# Finding the size of a deflated chunk of data

Tags: parsing, deflate

Let's suppose I have a chunk of deflated data (as in the `compressed data` right after the first 2 bytes and before the ADLER32 check in a zlib compressed file)

How can I know the length of that chunk? How can I find where it ends?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to get that information from some metadata external to the zlib block. (The same is true of the uncompressed size.) Or you could decompress and see where you end up.

Compressed blocks in deflate format are self-delimiting, so the decoder will terminate at the correct point (unless the datastream has been corrupted).

Most file storage and data transmission formats which include compressed data make this metadata available. But since it is not necessary for decompression, it is not stored in the compressed stream.

Comment: I don't have that information. I'm parsing a python zlib compressed file. As per the RFC http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1950 the size of the compressed data is not specified. Does that mean that I'll have to implement the entire deflate algo?

Comment: @alexandernst: not if you use zlib to decompress the data. And why wouldn't you? It's small, fast, freely-available and unencumbered, reliable, stable and widely used in mission-critical applications.

Comment: I don't have anything against zlib, it's just that I'm writing my own parser and I wanted to know how to get the size of the compressed data.

Comment: @alexandernst: I guess your options are to use zlib or rewrite it. I know which one I'd choose :-)

Comment: The problem is that I'm not going to be sure always what type of data I'm giving the parser and I'm not sure (but I'd say no from what I have read so far) if zlib can handle non-zlib-deflated data.

Comment: @alexandernst: zlib only handles the formats it creates. So you'll need to recognize the compression technique before invoking zlib. I'm certainly not suggesting that you just give the whole file to zlib (unless you know that the whole file consists of nothing but a compressed object); use zlib's low-level streaming interface to process the input until it reports that it has reached the end of the compressed data stream (at which point you will also know what part of the buffer is not part of the compressed stream). I fear this comment exchange is going off-topic, though...

Comment: ... It is really a very easy to use API and it is specifically designed for the case where you have streaming input and you want to handle the decompressed data in convenient chunks. I gather that you don't need to handle them at all, which is a very easy application of the API.

Comment: Not at all, we're completely staying on-topic here. Could you point me at some docs/examples where zlib is specifically used with an unknown length data?

Comment: Did you take a look at the example code at http://zlib.net/zlib_how.html on the zlib official site? It's a well-annotated explanation of the API. It starts with compressing, which is probably less interesting to you but possible worth reading anyway for the introduction to the API theory. The example of decompressing is about half-way down the page, starting with the sentence "Now we do the same thing for decompression". Note that zlib is not doing the I/O; it is just being fed data. Also, although Adler's exposition doesn't underline the fact, `strm.avail_in` is correct at the end of...

Comment: ...the input loop, so you can use that to see what part of the last input buffer has not been consumed. I suggest you spend some quality time with Mark's explanation, and if it doesn't fully make sense, feel free to ask another question about whatever confused you.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to find where it ends is to decompress it. deflate streams are self-terminating.